# How do I call the "Use as Fetch in Console" menu in the right-click options in developer mode of Firefox via JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, firefox, bookmarklet, firefox-developer-tools

I want to make a bookmarklet that can call an API.

This API requires login to the site, so I must use the right-click option in Firefox developer mode in the Network Monitor tab: "Use as Fetch in Console".

Now I need to be able to call this right-click option with a javascript code and do the rest myself.

Comment: JS on a web page can't access the text written in the console nor the mentioned contextmenu, or other DevTools.

Comment: Can you suggest another solution for this? @Teemu

Comment: APIs that have some access control normally provide a way to pass some account information or access token along with the request. Though, if your goal is to execute a request using the `fetch` API to log in to that page before calling an API, then you should integrate that `fetch()` call into your code.